# Obstruction to the existence of global resolution of coherent sheaf

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, coherent-sheaves

It is well known that any coherent sheaf on a complex manifold (or more generally on some complex spaces) admits locally a resolution with locally free sheaves. It is also well known that for non-algebraic manifolds in general there is no global resolution.

Now my question: is it some kind of invariant that prevents the local resolutions to glue to a global one?

Comment: this is a great question! a "high-level" answer would be that you have a global resolution when the associated twisting cochain (à la Toledo–Tong) is concentrated in degrees $0$ and $1$, which means that you could maybe consider the higher degrees as obstruction data

Comment: Dear @Andrei Halanay, would you mind giving a reference for the existence of local resolution with locally free sheaves on complex spaces? I have only seen it for complex manifolds.

Comment: @DougLiu The property holds on any ringed space. One reference is this : https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01BU

Comment: Dear @Andrei Halanay, I agree that for every coherent module $F$ on a ringed space $X$ and every $x\in X$, there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x\in X$ such that $F|_U$ is can be generated by finitely many sections, i.e., there is an integer $n\ge0$ and a quotient $\phi:O_U^n\to F|_U$. Moreover, the kernel of $\phi$ is of finite type. However, $\ker(\phi)$ may not be generated by finitely many sections over $U$. To get a quotient like $O^m\to \ker(\phi)$, we have to shrink $U$. As we may not have a finite-length resolution with finite locally free sheaves, we need infinite shrinkings.

Comment: Dear @DougLiu indeed it seems that the structure ring need to be regular. So I believe that the resolution property holds for a more general class then just complex manifolds but not for arbitrary complex spaces. So I'll edit the question accordingly.